# Python: class attributes haven't been found after defining

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I'm making a Tick Tack Toe game using classes in Python. A function inside of the class can't find attributes (I have set them, of course). I was only testing it now to see if the class works for me but it doesn't. What's wrong?

```
class ttt_sqs:
def __init__(self, column, row):
    self.column = column
    self.row = row

def position(self, column, row):
    self.position = self.column + self.row

from ttt_sqs import *

A1 = ttt_sqs("A", "1")
print(A1.position(ttt_sqs.column(), ttt_sqs.row()))
```

Comment: `column` and `row` are attributes, not functions. Don't try to call them... You probably need to read your material about classes again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ttt_sqs:
def __init__(self, column, row):
    self.column = column
    self.row = row

def position(self, column, row):
    self.position = self.column + self.row

from ttt_sqs import *

A1 = ttt_sqs("A", "1")
print(A1.position(A1.column, A1.row))
```

the `row` and `column` are object attributes, not functions. Also they are not static variables to be accessed using class name, hence you have to refer them using object.

Hope this solves your problem.